# Как в golang используя "gopkg.in/mgo.v2", разрешить чтение из слейвов?

Tags: golang, mongodb

Я пытаюсь создать коннект таким образом:

```
Host := []string{
  "replica1:27017",
  "replica2:27017",
  "replica3:27017",
}

const (
   Username = "username"
   Password = "pass"
   Database = "dbName"
   ReplicaSetName = "replicaName"
)

db, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(&mgo.DialInfo{
  Addrs:    Host,
  Username: Username,
  Password: Password,
  Database: Database,
  ReplicaSetName: ReplicaSetName,
})

db.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}

return db.Copy()
```

Для того чтобы разрешить чтение из вторичных реплик, я устанавливаю режим Monotonic, но это не помогло решить мою проблему

`db.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)`

Спустя какое то время получаю следующую ошибку:

`not master and slaveOk=false`

Comment: Можете ли Вы делать запросы к БД сразу после подключения? Корректно ли всё работает?

Comment: @hedgehogues да, сразу после подключения все нормально отрабатывает, видимо в какой-то момент потом мастер становится недоступен и оттуда появляется ошибка

Comment: Могли мастер упасть? Теоритически, в кластере мастер со слейвом могли поменяться.

Comment: Получилось поправить? Происходит ли такое всегда?

Comment: @hedgehogues Еще в процессе. Перенесла все на mongo-driver, будем смотреть, отпишу о результате

Comment: Мастер со слейвом скорее всего и меняются, просто монга об этом не знала, я перед запросами пинговала коннект, но это не спасло, попробуем на mongo-driver

Comment: Если на официальном драйвере не получится, пинганите меня ещё раз. Я подниму кластер и посмотрю.

Comment: @hedgehogues пока все работает исправно на бою, проблем не замечено! Если будут, я напишу об этом здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что использовать [этот](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/tree/v2-unstable) драйвер -- не самая хорошая идея. Автор явно говорит, что его поддержка прекращена. Кроме того, есть [официальный драйвер монги](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver). У него есть свои недостатки. Например, нельзя завести issue. По почте авторы не отвечают. Кроме того, возможно, Вам стоит явно указывать последний релиз в `go.mod`, чтобы избежать проблем, поскольку в мастере находится последний релиз + k коммитов. Иными словами, если Вы сделаете `go get -u https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver`, то получите более последний релиз + ряд коммитов, которые не входят в релиз (этот код, условно, можно назвать драфтом нового релиза, хотя он в реальности таковым не является).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую официальный драйвер